# Managing database tables in WordPress multisite

Tags: plugins, multisite, database

I'm working on plugin that creates and stores some data in database table (using global $wpdb->base_prefix). In WordPress multisite I want sub-website owners to have access only to data that they've created. What is the best way to handle this? Should I create new table for each sub-website, or add "blog_id" column to table and check it every time?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the API, the functions of WordPress for save data and check before, it is an Multisite install; thats all. The first example is only for check, is the activated as network wide.

```
// if is active in network of multisite
if ( is_multisite() && isset($_GET['networkwide']) && 1 == $_GET['networkwide'] ) {
    add_site_option( 'my_settings_id', $data );
} else {
    add_option( 'my_settings_id', $data );
}
```

The follow example check for mutlisite and if the plugin active in complete network.

```
if ( is_multisite() && is_plugin_active_for_network( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
    $values = get_site_option( 'my_settings_id' );
else
    $values = get_option( 'my_settings_id' );
```

Also you can check this in each blog and save the data in the tables of each blog.

*the examples was from [this post](http://wpengineer.com/2324/register-settings-on-wordpress-multisite/)